# Convert long table of linked observations to wide adjacency matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I am facing a challenge that I cannot manage to solve. I have a list of observations x_i (dimension is large, something around 30k) and a list of observations y_j (also large). x_i and y_i are id of the same units (say firms).

I have a dataframe of two columns that links `x_i` and `y_j`: if they appear on the same line, it means that they are connected. What I would like is to convert this network into a large matrix `M` of size `(unique(union(x, y)))` and which takes the value 1 if the two firms are connected.

Here is an example in small dimensions:

```
x1 x2
x3 x6
x4 x5
x1 x5
```

What I would like is a matrix:

```
0 1 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Right now, the only solution I could think of is a double loop combined with a search in the initial dataframe:

```
list_firm = union(as.vector(df[1]), as.vector(df[2]))
list_firm <- sort(list_firm[[1]])
list_firm <- unique(list_firm)
M <- Matrix(nrow = length(list_firm), ncol = length(list_firm))

for (i in list_firm) {
    for (j in list_firm) {
        M[i, j] = !is.null(which(df$col1 == i & df$col2 == j))
    }
}
```

Where `df` is the two columns data frame. This is obviously much too long to run.

Any suggestion? This would be very welcome

Comment: Try `df1[] <- lapply(df1, factor, levels = paste0("x", 1:6)); table(df1)`

Answer (score 1):

We convert the columns to `factor` with `levels` specified as the `unique` elements of both columns and get the frequency with `table`

```
lvls <- sort(unique(unlist(df)))
df[] <- lapply(df, factor, levels = lvls)
table(df)
#  col2
#col1 x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6
#  x1  0  1  0  0  1  0
#  x2  0  0  0  0  0  0
#  x3  0  0  0  0  0  1
#  x4  0  0  0  0  1  0
#  x5  0  0  0  0  0  0
#  x6  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(col1 = c("x1", "x3", "x4", "x1"), col2 = c("x2", 
 "x6", "x5", "x5")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L
 ))
```

Comment: Thanks! I had no idea it were that simple!

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided by @akrun in the comments is a good one. However, this is a good scenario to take advantage of a different data structure than data frames. Basically, what you're looking for is an adjacency matrix, which is a data structure in social network analysis. To achieve this, we can use the `igraph` package in R.

```
library(igraph)
library(dplyr)

df = data_frame(source=c('x1', 'x3', 'x4', 'x1'), target=c('x2', 'x6', 'x5', 'x5'))
g = graph_from_data_frame(df, directed=FALSE)
output = as.matrix(get.adjacency(g))

   x1 x3 x4 x2 x6 x5
x1  0  0  0  1  0  1
x3  0  0  0  0  1  0
x4  0  0  0  0  0  1
x2  1  0  0  0  0  0
x6  0  1  0  0  0  0
x5  1  0  1  0  0  0
```

The output columns aren't in the exact order as your example, but this is a trivial problem to solve if needed.

Comment: You can also use the `type` parameter of `get.adjacency` to get just the upper triangle of connections, which is closer to the desired output in your question.

Comment: The difference is that order matters in my case, so the output matrix shouldn't be symmetrics

Comment: Then you would want to use `get.adjacency(g, type="upper")` in that case. Or, make a directed graph to begin with. Either way, if you're dealing with this data a lot, I would highly recommend reading up on the igraph package if you haven't already. It's incredibly useful.

Comment: Thanks this was a very useful read (that I am still processing...). Just a quick remark, how would you adjust your code if there were no connexion between x3 and anything else, to still consider x3 in your output matrix? A bit like the level option in lapply did